# In Gnome, how to change the "Default Applications" / "Mail" to chrome-beta?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, google-chrome, email

The most recent stable version of Chrome (or at least 118 when I was testing) has been freezing in my laptop, so I installed Chrome-beta which is working much better.

Now the issue is that in Ubuntu 22.04.03, the "Default Applications" preferences does not show "Google Chrome (Beta)" as an option for "Mail" -- it does show it for "Browser" though.

Is there a way I can tell Gnome (and the system) to use "Google Chrome (Beta)" instead of "Google Chrome" ?

Many thanks!